# unable to search for a value using vim editor in a huge file in unix

Tags: string, unix, vim

I have a sample file abc.txt and I want to search the word "-ran" in the file .

Once I open the file in vim editor and hit an escape /ran it takes me to lines where I have the word "ransome".
I instead only need the word "ran"

Sample file pattern:
12,345,-ran,0.98
0
0.98
234
67
12,245,-ran,0.05
6
45
45

I have tried with vim and escape
/<,-ran/>  however the prompt reaches at words like ransome etc. And not the word -ran

Comment: Please take the time to format your question properly if you want others to take the time to give proper answers. Also, you mention `-ran`, `ran`, and `,-ran`; which one do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [vim help](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C)

> \<
> Matches the beginning of a word: The next char is the first char of a
> word.  The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.
> /zero-width

`-` nor `,` are word characters by default, so you can update `iskeyword` option or search for `-\<ran\>` to match **-ran** and not **-ransome**